# Segfault causes chrome to crash randomly ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to fix a problem with Chrome crashing. I checked the syslog and found that a segfault caused this:

```
kernel: [27188.655825] chrome[1950]: segfault at 8 ip 000055e90851b3b0 sp 00007ffc7082dfe0 error 4 in chrome[55e90747a000+686c000]
```

This seems to continue to happen and I'm trying to find a way to get this fixed.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and `google-chrome-stable`'s version is 48.0.2564.109-1. I'm unable to upgrade Chrome due to other dependencies.

Comment: In computing, a segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault) or access violation is a fault, or failure condition, raised by hardware with memory protection, notifying an operating system (OS) the software has attempted to access a restricted area of memory (a memory access violation). In simple terms a memory or sometimes a hard disk problem.

Comment: "Unable to upgrade chrome due to other dependencies." sounds strange. Latest Chrome version is about 92.0.4515.159-1 . Do you have correct repositories? What is your CPU architecture? How much RAM do you have? Have tested it using memtest86?

Comment: @N0rbert I am unable to upgrade it as there is an application running that has been particularly set up for chrome 48.0.2564.109-1 and as such I am trying to find a way to resolve this problem using a different approach. CPU Celeron J1900 & 4GB DDR3. Also I am unable to do a memtest as I am testing this remotely.

Comment: @angisl there is a package memtester in apt, that can be run in the terminal, but the downside is that it cannot test the entire RAM. To diagnose what chrome is doing before it segfaults, try strace: `strace -f google-chrome-stable > strace.log 2>&1`, but the output may be hard to read. And the third advice is to get the .deb file for that exact version of chrome, and reinstall it.